# img not showing in vuejs dynamic fetch from url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display image but **`{{Config:get('app.url')}`**} not fetching URL correctly

```
 <div id="app">
<div v-for="post in posts">
<img :src="'{{Config::get('app.url')}}/public/img/' + post.pic" width="100px" margin="10px" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: i'm not getting any error but i am getting wrong path in pic url  http://localhost/public/img/male.png ,, it missing the real path which is http://localhost/project/public/img/male.png

Comment: show your APP_URL in .env file

Comment: in env. APP_URL=http://localhost ,still getting same .not working

Comment: I mean your code gives the path `'{{Config::get('app.url')}}/public/img/'` which is basicly `'localhost/public/img/'` so i dont get your problem ?

Comment: after localhost ,it is missing one folder which contains /public/img..

Comment: Yes but you dont give that url?

Comment: where have to set Url in config/app.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this app url

```
APP_URL=localhost/project
```

and

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: are you using virtual host or `php artisan server`

Comment: php artisan server

Comment: what if i include project folder name which missing there like /project/public/img

Comment: can you give me an idea where is your project folder

Comment: i got img url like  localhost/public/img/male.png but real path is  localhost/project/public/img/male.png

Comment: and what ulr  in config/app.php

Comment: stop your server and do this `php artisan config:clear`  and in env `APP_URL=localhost/project` remains this line it will work for you I have tried this

Comment: yes its working thank you, but do you think this is the right way to show image files?

Comment: it depend what type of image you are showing if it is static th ok if dainamic then not ok

Answer (score -1):

In your .env file change APP_URL to localhost/project

Note: Never show public in the url.

Suggestion: Please use virtual host in order to work properly with laravel projects.